# Chingu: How do I add a custom mouse cursor to my game?

Tags: ruby

With Chingu, what is the best way to create a custom mouse cursor image? I'm able to get a custom cursor on the screen, but it seems awkward. Relevant code:

```
class Game < Chingu::Window
    def initialize
        super
        self.input = { :escape => :exit }
        #@cursor = false
        @cursor = Gosu::Image.new(self, 'media/mouse.png')
    end

    def draw
        super
        @cursor.draw(self.mouse_x, self.mouse_y, 100)
    end

    def needs_cursor?
        false
    end 
end
```

Perceived issues with this...

1. I need to use the Gosu needs_cursor? method to hide the system cursor, @cursor=false doesn't seem to work.
2. It seems wrong to me to use Gosu::Image.

Is there a better way? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no dedicated mechanism for that.
Also thats the way it is done in other 2D game engines, as well.

Remember to offset your image so the click point is at the position of your mouse (e.g. the middle of a sniper cross)

1. I use this:

   ```
   Game < Chingu::Window
     def initialize
       super(640,480,false)              
       self.cursor = false
     end
   end
   ```

   So setting the `cursor` variable works just fine. What Chingu version are you using? Also I cannot imagine there were changes to that.
2. Actually `Gosu::Image` is a pretty good choice since everything else in Chingu also uses that class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Chingu version is 0.8.1. Setting self.cursor = false seems to do nothing in my code. def needs_cursor? does get rid of it however.